# Binding a collection inside a data source object to a DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, objectdatasource, bindingsource

I do have two sql server database tables, which are Machine and Fault. Machine table have all the information regarding a specific machine here on my site. Fault table stores all mechanical faults associated with a specific machine, that is, one machine can have many faults (one to many relationship). I do have a data source that is binded to the Machine object. Which means as a result I do have a collection of Faults inside this object. I am using the Windows Form control BindingNavigator to navigate to each machine in my system. I am able to view each machine information. However, I am struggling to view all the faults that is associated with the selected machine in DataGridView. How can I get all the faults associated with machine in DataGridView. On my Machine class I have a get property that is returning all the faults given a MachineID.  So, within my Machine object Faults property is returning a collection of faults like indicated on the below code. Please assist?

```
public override ICollection<Fault> Faults
{
        get
        {
            //returning all faults associated with a given machine
            using (var context = new AllEntities())
            {
                var faultsList = (from f in context.Faults
                                  where f.MachineID == MachineID
                                  select f).ToList<Fault>();

                return faultsList; //return the list of faults
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think you have to use `DataRelation`s to view hierarchical data in the standard DataGridView. See this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28276/DataGridView-with-hierarchical-data-binding . Another option could be to use two grids in master/detail format.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to bind the master grid via [`BindingSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource(v=vs.110).aspx) and then bind the detail grid **DataSource** property to the same binding source.

Here is a full working demo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Samples
{
    public class Master
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Detail> Details { get; set; }
    }

    public class Detail
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            var form = new Form();
            var split = new SplitContainer { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, Parent = form, Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };
            var dgvMaster = new DataGridView { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, Parent = split.Panel1 };
            var dgvDetail = new DataGridView { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, Parent = split.Panel2 };
            var data = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(p => new Master
            {
                Name = "P" + p,
                Details = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(c => new Detail
                {
                    Name = "C" + p + "." + c,
                }).ToList()
            }).ToList();

            var bsMaster = new BindingSource { DataSource = data };
            dgvMaster.DataSource = bsMaster;
            dgvDetail.DataBindings.Add("DataSource", bsMaster, "Details", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.Never);

            Application.Run(form);
        }
    }
}
```

The essential part is:

```
var bsMaster = new BindingSource { DataSource = data };
dgvMaster.DataSource = bsMaster;
dgvDetail.DataBindings.Add("DataSource", bsMaster, "Details", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.Never);
```

Replace `Master` with `Machine`, `Detail` with `Fault`, "Details" with "Faults` and the result will be your model.

Comment: Thank you @Ivan. It seems I am getting there. However, my bsMaster does not have any data. I am now able to have the dataGridView displayed but without any data on it.  I am thinking I am getting stuck on the query that returns only Faults on with the same MachineID as the Master Machine.MachineID. I am using LINQ to Entities and here is my code which I am sure its not doing the right thing. Please help me

Comment: It's hard to tell what's the exact problem w/o having [mcve]. The query looks ok, the only strange thing is that the query is executed on each property getter - consider using a backing field. But again, this might or might not be the problem. If you can provide reproducible example, I'll be glad to help, otherwise there is nothing I can do,